# Comparing two lists and outputting differences in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, arrays, xslt

I have started this again, i was trying to get my head round the basics of this and have failed, below is the structure the XML will most likely take. and then what i need to output below that...

```
 <rtpm>
    <old>
        <simple>
            <information>
                <name1code>AAA</name1code>
                <name1use>N</name1use>
                <name2code>BBB</name2code>
                <name2use>P</name2use>
                <name3code>CCC</name3code>
                <name3use>N</name3use>
                <name4code>DDD</name4code>
                <name4use>N</name4use>
                <name5code>EEE</name5code>
                <name5use>N</name5use>
            </information>  
        </simple>
    </old>
    <new>
        <simple>
            <information>
                <name1code>AAA</name1code>
                <name1use>N</name1use>
                <name2code>BBC</name2code>
                <name2use>P</name2use>
                <name3code>AFD</name3code>
                <name3use>N</name3use>
                <name4code>CCC</name4code>
                <name4use>N</name4use>
                <name5code>EEE</name5code>
                <name5use>N</name5use>
            </information>
        </simple>
    </new>
</rtpm>
```

I would then need this to perform what was previously described and output as

```
<request>
    <query0>BBC</query0>
    <use0>P</use0>
    <query1>AFD</query1>
    <use1>N</use1>
</request>
```

The code currently in use is as per below but i have no idea how to make it just pick up name1code, 2code etc for the old key
and the use to just pick up the use value when a 'not' match is found for the code.

```
  <xsl:key name="old" match="old/simple/information/*" use="." />
<xsl:key name="use" match="new/simple/information/*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
<request>
    <xsl:for-each select="new/simple/information/*[not(key('old', .))]">
        <xsl:element name="query{position() - 1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="use{position() - 1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('use', concat(name(), 'use'))" /> <!--2-->        
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</request>
</xsl:template>
```

`<!--2-->` is the line i can't get my head around.

Thank you too all that have helped so far, you have been a huge help. i say i have failed getting my head round it, but i get what/how this works to a degree, just not how to further it.

Comment: Which processor are you using?  This will probably be simplest as a two-phase transformation but that requires that your processor supports some sort of `node-set` extension function (msxsl or exslt).

Comment: Are the two xml samples part of one document, or two separate documents? Also, could you show the output you expect in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Tim C - Same document, split by old/new parent fields
Will amend the above with some example outputs
Ian Roberts - I am unsure if we support the above in this area, looking at existing work within there, Nothing exists that uses a node-set

Comment: *"output any of the above where the value is different between old/new"*  Your second example shows something different, I think: output any value that does not appear **anywhere** in the old list - i.e do not try to match on element names. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct, anything in the new that does not appear anywhere in the old, however if the field that is different is name2Code, i need to be able to output name2use as per the output below.

Comment: Do you have any control over the input format? I think this version (what is it, the third by now?) is really awkward. And so is the requested output. XML has all the required depth to avoid the need for numbering alike elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a key to look up the old values

```
<xsl:key name="old" match="old/*" use="text()" />
```

Then, to select **new** elements with values don't occur in the list of **old** elements, you would simply do this (assuming you were positioned on **rtpm**)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="new/*[not(key('old', text()))]" />
```

And in the template that matches this, to create the relevant **query** element, you would make use of the **position()** function (***as this is relative to the nodes you have just selected, not the position of them in the hierarchy***)

```
 <xsl:element name="query{position() - 1}">
   <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
 </xsl:element>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:key name="old" match="old/*" use="text()" />
   <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="new/*[not(key('old', text()))]" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="new/*">
     <xsl:element name="query{position() - 1}">
       <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
     </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on your first XML sample, the following is output

```
<query0>ABB</query0>
<query1>ACD</query1>
```

In the second case, the following is also output

```
<query0>ABB</query0>
<query1>ACD</query1>
```

**EDIT:** The question has changed somewhat since it was originally asked (It should really have been asked as a new question), but to answer this new question, the expression in `<!-- 2 -->` you are looking for is this

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('use', concat(substring-before(name(), 'code'), 'use'))" />
```

This is because the current node has a name of "nameXcode", and it needs to be changed to "nameXuse" to look it up in the key. So, you get the text before "code" and then append "use" on the end instead.

However, if the **use** node you are getting is always going to be the following sibling to the **code** node, you could just do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]" />
```

This will work because **following-sibling** will get the following sibling in the hierarchy for the current node you are on, and not the next one in the nodes you have just selected.

Comment: +1, and "`position()` is relative to the nodes you have just selected, not their position in the hierarchy" should be in bold-italic :-)

Comment: You sir, are my absolute hero, i was trying using choose and whens and ifs and about 400lines later i was no closer to it! that has worked an absolute treat!

Comment: I may of hit an issue...Warning: at xsl:stylesheet on line 1 of file:/C:/eclipse_workspace/TestRequest.xslt:
  Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor

Comment: Ignore that, i have been an idiot, these particular service is running 2.0 not 1.0, so ill just amend the stylesheet and all should be good....

Comment: I've made the comment about position into bold italic!

Comment: Hmmm trying to think further down the line of this and struggling to figure out how to do another small part... after each output of each query, there needs to be a few other fields that will output information dependant on the name that is being output.. I will post more detail above

Comment: I think michael.hor257k has given you a fine answer to this, although it might have been better to have your posted the follow-up issue as a whole new question to avoid the original question getting to unwieldy. Thanks!

Comment: There is a problem here: if any one of the new `<nameXuse>` elements contains a value that isn't already used by an old one, it will have the template `match=new/*` applied to it. That's what I meant when I said earlier that the format is awkward. In order to handle it reliably, you need to apply string functions to the element names, which is not what XML is about.

Answer (score 1):

Re your followup question: not sure what exactly "following by a tag" means. In any case, the answer is (again) to use a key to match "related" values, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="old" match="old/*" use="." />
<xsl:key name="use" match="detail/*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<output>
    <xsl:for-each select="rtpm/new/*[not(key('old', .))]">
        <xsl:element name="query{position() - 1}">
            <value><xsl:value-of select="." /></value>
            <use><xsl:value-of select="key('use', concat(name(), 'use'))" /></use>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</output>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```