# Using a key and loop to identify differences in large lists, only picking out fields ending in a certain value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Below is the XML and then a brief explanation and some code, followed by what I need from you guys!

```
<rtpm>
    <old>
        <simple>
            <information>
                <name1code>AAA</name1code>
                <name1use>A</name1use>
                <name2code>BBB</name2code>
                <name2use>B</name2use>
                <name3code>CCC</name3code>
                <name3use>C</name3use>
                <name4code>DDD</name4code>
                <name4use>D</name4use>
                <name5code>EEE</name5code>
                <name5use>E</name5use>
            </information>  
        </simple>
    </old>
    <new>
        <simple>
            <information>
                <name1code>AAA</name1code>
                <name1use>F</name1use>
                <name2code>BBC</name2code>
                <name2use>G</name2use>
                <name3code>AFD</name3code>
                <name3use>H</name3use>
                <name4code>CCC</name4code>
                <name4use>I</name4use>
                <name5code>EEE</name5code>
                <name5use>J</name5use>
            </information>
        </simple>
    </new>
</rtpm>
```

I have some code which checks if anything in New/simple/information is not present anywhere in the old/simple/information

What I need to do is find a way to make it only check fields that end in "code".
As there could be 20 name1#### fields and then 20 name2#### fields, however, I am only interested in the name1code, name2code etc...

So, the above XML would put output as

```
<request>
    <type></type>
    <query0>BBC</query0>
    <data0>G</data0>
    <field0>A</field0>
    <query1>AFD</query1>
    <data1>H</data1>
    <field1>B</field1>
</request>
```

to expand further, i need to find any code's that are not present in the old, but are in the new, output them as query0, then query1 etc. and pick up other bits of information and apply those in data and field. 
This has to be an field/element name of query0, query1, and cannot be an attribute, as the server receiving the XML will be looking for those exact fields.

```
<xsl:key name="old" match="old/simple/information/*" use="." />
<xsl:key name="use" match="new/simple/information/*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
<request>
    <type>A</type>
    <xsl:for-each select="new/simple/information/*[not(key('old', .))]">
        <xsl:element name="query{position() - 1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element> 
    </xsl:for-each>
</request>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This seems to be a direct continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404318/comparing-two-lists-and-outputting-differences-in-xslt-1-0 Not sure why you need to re-open this in a new question. In the previous thread I asked if you have any control over the input format, precisely because of the problem which you now present.

Comment: i have no control over the format of the input XML unfortunately.

Comment: For crying out loud, Jonathan! Can't you make up your mind about what you have and what you need to have? You can't constantly kaizen your requirements and expect people to keep up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Please first address the comment by @michael.hor257k on a [previous question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404318/comparing-two-lists-and-outputting-differences-in-xslt-1-0) before asking a new one! Otherwise, you are simply doubling the time and effort people spend on your questions.

I agree with the answers and comments on your previous question: your XML input is especially poorly designed in the first place. If anything, start by rethinking how your input is presented.

Use the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[ends-with(name(),'code') and ancestor::new and not(ancestor::new/preceding-sibling::old/descendant::*[ends-with(name(),'code') and .=current()])]">
      <query>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </query>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query>BBC</query>
<query>AFD</query>
```

**EDIT**: The essence of a lot of comments:

In general, the position of an element does not need to be stored and it does overcomplicate your output XML enormously. The position of elements can easily be determined without having it appear in the element name.

It is widely agreed that elements with the same semantics should also carry the same name - so, all those elements should be named `query`. If this is really a requirement, use an attribute for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query pos="1">BBC</query>
<query pos="2">AFD</query>
```

You do not have control over the input format, as you say, but perhaps you could still prevent your stylesheet from outputting poor design?

Comment: I have no control over how i am sent the input unfortunately, and i agree completely that it is poorly laid out, thus the need for all of this... I re-posted the question as i had changed the last question 3 times and unfortunately i cannot give people credit for correct answers to three different problems, so i thought it best to create a new one instead of changing it again and again.

Comment: The above answer solves parts of the problems, form my initial testing, however it does not allow me to output as quesr0, query1 etc. the rpeviously used <xsl:element name="pc{position() - 1}"> does not appear to work (creates 67/69) in my testing.

Comment: The position of an element does not _need_ to be stored and it does overcomplicate your output XML enormously. The position of elements can easily be determined without having it appear in the element name.

Comment: It is widely agreed that elements with the same semantics should also carry the same name - so, all those elements should be names `query`. If this is really a requirement, use an attribute for this.

Comment: I stripping down an XML into a set of data and then passing this to be transformed into HTTPGET, the HTTPGET needs me to send information in format such as query0, data0, field0, query1,data1,field1 etc. for each 'difference' found, i will detail more in the question around ym example output.

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaptation of my previous answer to the <strike>current</strike> input/output requirements **presented in your question here, before you changed them once again**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="oldCode" match="old/simple/information/*[contains(name(), 'code')]" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">
<request>
    <xsl:for-each select="rtpm/new/simple/information/*[contains(name(), 'code')][not(key('oldCode', .))]">
        <xsl:element name="query{position() - 1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</request>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I agree with Mathias Müller regarding the output being just as badly formatted as the input. I don't know if you have any say in *that* at least.